# @font-family, strange font name - can I rename?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

For example, I'm using the 04B_19__ font and it is most certainly a weird name I'd like to rename it if possible. Here's how my current code looks for implementing it using @font-family:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: '04B_19__';
  src: url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.eot') %>');
  src: url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.eot') %>t') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'),
  url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'),
  url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.svg#04B_19__') %>') format('svg');
}
```

What's the best way to rename the font to something more generic like: "boxy-font" for example.

Comment: You can all your font anything you like in the font-family declaration provided the source files relate to that font.

Answer (score 3):

`font-family` is just a name you have assigned to that collection of font files.

You can just change it to:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'boxy-font';
  src: url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.eot') %>');
  src: url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.eot') %>t') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'),
  url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'),
  url('<%= font_path('04b_19__-webfont.svg#04B_19__') %>') format('svg');
}
```

and everything will work fine.

Comment: This is correct. You can also rename the files to match, if you desire.